# How to parse values from a file that I select through the FileChooser class?

Tags: java

I have a JavaFX application that has a "load text" button. When you click this button, you need to select a file and load information from it by class (its fields)

1. How to make such logic? Which file should I choose (serialized or write data of an arbitrary class just to a file without serialization)?
2. How to parse these values? That is, there are 3 test fields in the class and how can I get these values ​​of my arbitrary class when I click on the "load message" button

Button FXML:

```
<Button fx:id="buttonLoadMessage"
        layoutX="261.0"
        layoutY="66.0"
        mnemonicParsing="false"
        prefHeight="25.0"
        prefWidth="169.0"
        text="load message">
```

the button does not have onaction since I did not create a method for this logic, because I do not understand how to

Comment: Parsing the file is in no way related on how you select the file to parse, so it is not a problem with JavaFX. It is just a matter of the contents of that file and the desired target format after parsing it. Therefore it would help a lot if you would specify both in detail.

Comment: I have two questions. How should I write information to a file (serialize a class or just write its data to a file)? And the second question: how do I just select a file through FileChooser and get data from it?

Comment: You just repeated the question (*after* failing to supply info you were asked for). Question likely to be closed

Comment: I repeat once again that the meaning of the question is precisely in the analysis. And I don't understand how FileChooser works at all. How do I select a text or serialized file via FileChooser and get the text from that file

Comment: I voted to close because scope is way too wide. I suggest you spend time looking at each stage of your problem: look at samples for using FileChooser, java.nio.file.Files class for file handling, and then come back to registering your JavaFX button action handler which links up all of those. There are many tutorials and SO questions on each topic.

Comment: Not understanding how `FileChooser` works at all: try a tutorial or two. They will help you a lot better than a Stack Overflow question.